# where to store images?

Tags: android, imageview

I am creating an app that uses more than two hundred images. To display images, lmageView is used. My question is- Is it necessary to put images in drawable-hdpi,drawable-mdpi,drawable-xhdpi,drawable-xxhdpi. If I put the images in these four folders, does my app size increases?
Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess if your image set will not change in the future maybe that's the best place to store them.  Your app size will certainly increase, however, if that's a concern you can store them using any cloud service like [parse.com](http://www.parse.com) or [firebase](https://www.firebase.com/), so you can retrieve them later using a library like [picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to put pictures in all folders. There are folders for different image resolutions. You can use a single folder called drawable or just use drawable-mdpi. The app size increase with multiple image versions. There are some disadvantages when you use only one folder.

If you have big resolution images inside your folder: For a presentation, small screen devices have to minimize the image. This costs hardware ressources. If it costs to much ressources, your app will crash. 
If you have small resolution images inside your folder: For a presentation, big screen devices have to upscale the image. This will result in bad image quality.